# How to get the Clover report displayed in Jenkins, when using pipelines?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, clover

I'm setting up a Jenkins project for a PHP project. I installed the [Clover](https://plugins.jenkins.io/clover/) plugin and want to see Clover reports on my project's page. Following the [Clover plugin pipeline documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/clover/) I added this snippet to my pipeline:

```
step([
    $class:'CloverPublisher',
    cloverReportDir: 'build/coverage',
    cloverReportFileName: 'build/logs/clover.xml',
    healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 70, statementCoverage: 70],
    unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50],
    failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]
])
```

The relevant folder `build/coverage` and file `build/logs/clover.xml` exist:

```
$ cd /path/ma/project
$ ls build/coverage
ModuleA ModuleB ModuleC dashboard.html index.html
$ ls build/logs
clover.xml  crap4j.xml  junit.xml
```

But there is no Clover report displayed on the Jenkins project page. Instead of this only a new link `OpenClover HTML Report` is shown in the build's navigation. This link leads to the HTML coverage report.

**What am I doing wrong? How to get the Clover report displayed?**

---

**`Jenkinsfile`**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label params.LABEL
            customWorkspace params.PROJECT_ROOT
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'hostname'
                sh 'pwd'
            }
        }
        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Test"'
                // sh './vendor/bin/phpunit ./test/Unit'
                sh 'vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite "unit-app-only"'
                step([
                    $class: 'XUnitBuilder',
                    tools: [
                        PHPUnit([
                            pattern: 'build/logs/junit.xml',
                            skipNoTestFiles: true,
                            failIfNotNew: false,
                            deleteOutputFiles: false,
                            stopProcessingIfError: true
                        ])
                    ]
                ])
                step([
                    $class:'CloverPublisher',
                    cloverReportDir: 'build/coverage',
                    cloverReportFileName: 'build/logs/clover.xml',
                    healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 70, statementCoverage: 70],
                    unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50],
                    failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]
                ])
                publishHTML([
                    allowMissing: true,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'build/coverage',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'HTML Publisher Report'
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was caused by a wrong path to the Clover report (`cloverReportDir` and `cloverReportFileName`). Now it works. I'm going to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed the Clover plugin and if the path to the `clover.xml` is correct (for example in my case the path is `'''/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Front-Test-Coverage/intellst-front/output/coverage/jest'''`)

[Clover plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWA9F.png)